# How come $\frac{1}{\cos x} = 1 + \frac{x^{2}}{2} + o(x^{2})$ as $x \to 0$?

Tags: calculus, limits, taylor-expansion

Since 
$$\cos x = 1 - \frac{x^{2}}{2} + o(x^{3})$$
as 
$x \to 0,$
we have
$$\frac{1}{\cos x} = \frac{1}{1-\frac{x^{2}}{2} + o(x^{3})} = 1 + \frac{x^{2}}{2} + o(x^{3}) + o(\frac{-x^{2}}{2} + o(x^{3})).$$
But I do not see how to write the term on the extreme right as $o(x^{2})$.

Comment: Since $|x|<1$, higher powers are lesser than smaller ones.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may recall that
$$
\frac{1}{1-u}=1+u+O(u^2), \quad u \to 0.
$$
Thus
$$
\frac{1}{\cos x} = \frac{1}{1-\frac{x^{2}}{2} + o(x^{3})} = 1 + \frac{x^{2}}{2} + o(x^{3}) + O(\frac{-x^{2}}{2} + o(x^{3}))^2
$$ then use
$$
O(\frac{-x^{2}}{2} + o(x^{3}))^2 =o(x^{3}).
$$

Comment: There is a typo I believe, you could use $O(x^3)$ instead of $o(x^2)$ above, but not $o(x^3)$

Comment: You are right! @orangeskid typo corrected. Thanks.